# convert a greek file name into latin one in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I would be gratefull if someone could help me with this problem!
I have an empty file (in real program there is some data in it) and its name contains greek letters e.g. "Σ2262.txt". My goal is to convert all greek letters in latin, for example the greek letter "Σ" to latin "S". My code is as follows:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(FOLDER_PATH, topdown=True):
    for name in filenames:
        if name.endswith('2262.txt'):
            old_name = name
            #new = re.sub('Σ', 'S', name)
            for char in name:
                print char
                #print grToLat.get(char)
                name = re.sub(char, grToLat.get(char), name)
            print "GrToLat: "+ name
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, old_name),os.path.join(dirpath, name))
```

I have also constructed a dictionary that maps each greek letter to the corresponding latin one as below:

```
grToLat = {
'Α':'A', 'α':'a', 'ά':'a', 'Β':'B', 'β':'b',
'Γ':'G', 'γ':'g', 'Δ':'D', 'δ':'d', 'Ε':'E',
'έ':'e', 'ε':'e', 'Ζ':'Z', 'ζ':'z', 'Η':'H',
'η':'h', 'ή':'h', 'Θ':'U', 'θ':'u', 'Ι':'I',
'ι':'i', 'ί':'i', 'Κ':'K', 'κ':'k', 'Λ':'L',
'λ':'l', 'Μ':'M', 'μ':'m', 'Ν':'N', 'ν':'n',
'Ξ':'J', 'ξ':'j', 'Ο':'O', 'ο':'o', 'ό':'o',
'Π':'P', 'π':'p', 'Ρ':'R', 'ρ':'r', 'Σ':'S',
'ς':'s', 'σ':'s', 'Τ':'T', 'τ':'t', 'Υ':'Y',
'ύ':'y', 'υ':'y', 'Φ':'F', 'φ':'f', 'Χ':'X',
'χ':'x', 'Ψ':'C', 'ψ':'c', 'ω':'v', 'ώ':'v',
'Ω':'V'
}
```

where FOLDER_PATH contains my file.
With the above code It seems that the greek letter "Σ" does not map to any latin letter. What is strange about this is that even if we uncomment the line and try it hardcoded nothing happens again!

```
new = re.sub('Σ', 'S', name)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am using python2 my operating system is windows 10.

Comment: You certainly don't need a regex for that job. `.replace()` would suffice.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Have you tried Python 3? In Python 2 you're probably getting the file names in an incompatible encoding.

Comment: windows 10 @usr2564301

Comment: You need to prefix all strings with `u` prefix.